# Ruby on Rails format validation (yyyy/yyyy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, string-formatting

I'm working on a project for college and it's Yearbook project. I need to put years in exact format yyyy/yyyy (eg. 2014/2015) can anyone help me to parse and make a validation?

P.S. I've been searching for a while how to parse it and I've searched all built in date format validations, but so far, I couldn't find anything.
P.P.S. I'm kinda new to ruby and rails but I'm trying to learn, so have patience please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate that string with a simple regular expression (regex)

```
regex = /^\d{4}\/\d{4}$/

"2014/2015" =~ regex # => 0 # non-nil means that string matched
"blah2014/2015" =~ regex # => nil # no match
"201/2015" =~ regex# => nil # no match
```

Now the (even more) simple part I leave for your homework: find out how to build a regex model validator on top of this. It is easily googlable.

Comment: thank you very much, made it like this:
validates_format_of :year, :with => /\A\d{4}\/\d{4}\z/, :message => "Invalid! Format must be yyyy/yyyy"


btw. I don't know what's with the down-votes, I've really tried to google everything with "parsing" "formating" and never run to regex, otherwise I would solve it myself. But I'm really new to ruby and rails (and they don't teach us that technology in college) so I've never heard of it, sorry